# Why $dz\wedge d\bar{z} = d|z|\wedge d\phi$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\bar{z}$ its complex conjugate. Then, a Kahler form can be written as $k = dz \wedge d\bar{z}$. If we re-write $z=|z|e^{i\phi}$ how do we get that

$$dz\wedge d\bar{z} = d|z|\wedge d\phi$$

or what is the correct answer? I have some handwritten notes here but I cannot understand why this is.

Comment: What does “$dz$” mean if $z$ is an actual complex number?

Comment: I think it refers to the exterior derivative.

Comment: But what is the exterior derivative of a complex number?

Comment: This is like a symplectic product. In classical mechanics one construct the symplectic product of the phase space as the wedge product of the exterior derivatives of the coordinates and the momenta: $dx \wedge dp$. This should be analogous.

Comment: @k.stm : All $z$, $|z|$, $\phi$ can be treated as functions on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @k.stm $dz_i = \frac{\partial z_i}{\partial z_j}dz_j$ I think..

Comment: @Marion: The Kahler form should be $\frac{i}{2} dz \wedge d\bar z$.

Comment: And the result should be something like $|z|d|z|\wedge d\phi$

Comment: @John yes, you are right. But as for the result is concerned I am not sure if marwalix is right. My calculation yields a $|z|$ as he/she says but also an additional $e^{i\phi}$.

Answer (score 4):

There are three (standard?) coordinate on $\mathbb C$, the complex one ($z$), the real one $z = x+iy$ and the polar one $(r, \phi)$,

The standard Kahler form is $dx\wedge dy$. Which is the same as $\frac{i}{2} dz \wedge d\bar z$ as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{i}{2} dz\wedge d\bar z &= \frac i2 d(x+ i y) \wedge d(x - iy)\\
&= \frac i2 (dx + idy) \wedge (dx - idy) \\
&= \frac i2 (-idx \wedge dy + i dy \wedge dx) \\
&= \frac 12 (dx \wedge dy + dx \wedge dy)\\
&= dx \wedge dy.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, if we use polar coordinate $(r, \phi)$, then $r^2 =x^2 + y^2 $ and $\phi = \tan^{-1}\frac yx$.

Thus

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
rdr \wedge d\phi &= \frac 12 d(r^2) \wedge d \left(\tan^{-1}\frac yx\right) \\
&=\frac 12 d(x^2 + y^2) \wedge d \left(\tan^{-1}\frac yx\right) \\
&= \frac 12 (2xdx + 2ydy)  \wedge \left( \frac{-y dx}{x^2+ y^2} +\frac{x dy}{x^2+ y^2}\right)\\
&= dx \wedge dy. 
\end{split}
\end{equation}